# MVC: How to pass back next page url in the html to the client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, infinite-scroll

We have infinite scroll page and we are getting html from the MVC conroller server side i.e.

```
<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
```

We need to send back next page url to the javascript client so that if user scrolls to bottom, it can issue request to server to fetch next set of listings.

We have next page url on server. The JS client needs to hit this URL to get next set of listings.

I don't have any clear idea how can i send this next page url from server to the client. One way could be to bind the next page url inside the last `<li>...</li>`tag and read it from the last `<li>...</li>`tag on the client.

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: Are you sending back raw data or is it already in html format?

Comment: sending back html from MVC controller

Comment: Since you are sending back html, I would put a hidden li at the end with a data attribute on it with the url.  `<li data-url="blah" class="hidden next-url"></li>` and then use jquery to snag the url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure how your request's response looks like currently, but if possible, I'd restructure your response's payload from the server to look like:

```
{
  nextPage: 'someUrl',
  data: '<li>...</li>'
}
```

that way you don't have to hide the URL into the markup and your view and controller logic stay separated :)

Comment: Correct. But we want to load our page on javascript disabled browsers too. If we start sending back JSON response instead of HTML, it would stop working on JS disabled browsers. Any other elegant way we can solve this?

Comment: how would infinite scroll work on JS-disabled browsers? I didn't mean to send the nextPage URL on the initial page request, just for the consequent requests that query for the next element. I think you could make those queries separate from the way you'd request an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

After your last li tag you can use script tag and store value of next-page-url in global variable. And then you can easily get that value whenever you need.

```
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
<script>nextPageUrl="@Model.nextPageUrl";</script>
```

This way you don't have to bind URL in last li tag.

Comment: This would create a global javascript variable. We can also achieve this by having nextPageUrl in a div tag. I am not sure which one is better though.

Comment: But accessing variable of JS is very much faster then the accessing value from div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning html, just return the url in a data tag on the li.

```
<li data-next-page="www.google.com/foo/bar">stuff</li>
```

Then, use the following jQuery to get it next time.

```
var nextUrl = $('#ulContainer').find('li').last().data('next-page');
```